# Don't understand cause of this ValueError when resizing image in PIL

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

When I run my code it gives me an strange error which I haven't seen before. This is the error:
`ValueError: Unknown resampling filter (400). Use Image.NEAREST (0), Image.LANCZOS (1), Image.BILINEAR (2), Image.BICUBIC (3), Image.BOX (4) or Image.HAMMING (5)`

Here is my code:

```
import re, requests, io
import PIL, PIL.Image, PIL.ImageOps, PIL.ImageSequence

imgurl = 'https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/table-wooden-floor-natural-lanescape-260nw-1895905258.jpg'
download = requests.get(imgurl)

type(download.content)

right_img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(download.content))
right_img_resized =  right_img.resize(400, 400) # <-- HERE IT GIVES ME AN ERROR
right_img_developed = right_img_resized.transform((400, 300), PIL.Image.QUAD, data=(0, 0, 100, 300, 300, 400, 400, 0), reshape=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)

left_img_url = re.sub('FRB', 'FLB', imgurl)
left_img = PIL.Image.open(io.BytesIO(requests.get(left_img_url).content))

left_img_resized = left_img.resize(400, 400)
left_img_developed = left_img_resized.transform((400, 300), PIL.Image.QUAD, data=(0, 0, 100, 300, 300, 400, 400, 0), reshape=PIL.Image.BILINEAR)

red_img = PIL.ImageOps.colorize(right_img_developed, (0,0,0), (255, 0, 0))
cylan_img = PIL.ImageOps.colorize(left_img_developed, (0, 0, 0)), (0, 255, 255)

blend = PIL.Image.blend(red_img, cylan_img, 0.5)
brightness = PIL.ImageEnhance.Brightness(blend)
image_3d = brightness.enhance(1.75)
image_3d.show()
```

Answer (score 3):

Try giving input in tuple as `right_img.resize((400, 400))`. Also the `left_img.resize` should be changed. Let me know if this helps.Reference: [Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.resize)

Comment: Thanks for your effort but i tryed what you sudgested and it works but than it gives me another error which is in line 11 :TypeError: transform() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reshape' Any ideas?

Comment: Yes, because there is no method like it. I think you should refer to `resample` instead of reshape

Comment: Thanks this works. But i got another error in line 19 (about coloring to red): assert image.mode == "L"
AssertionError.

Comment: @gapi31: It means what the error message says. Again, refer to the PIL [documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) of the [`transfprm()`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.transform) method. I believe reshaping is a `numpy` module array operation.

Comment: @Anupam  i got another error in line 19 (about coloring to red): assert image.mode == "L" AssertionError. any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: I think it uses only grayscale image and you have to give tuples RGB which you want instead of black and white. Refer here: [Documentation](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.0/reference/ImageOps.html#PIL.ImageOps.colorize)